# Increasing code capacity - good or bad?

Tags: android

I get these following few sentences in the Android Monitor while I'm running my app, and I'm wondering if it's a good or bad thing?

> Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB After code
>   cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB Increasing code cache capacity
>   to 128KB

The only thing I can think of is causing this is the fact that I continuously replace fragments in my activity using `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. I have tested my app for memory leaks by rotation the screen between landscape and portrait but I'm not getting any - i.e none of the "skipped x frames!" errors are coming up. So I don't know if this increasing code cache could be a problem and if I should do anything about it. What could be causing it and could it be a problem?

Comment: Could you figure it out? What was the probleme?